# What R Shiny layout would allow me to insert a map plot as the background of the entire page?

Tags: r, shiny

So think of Google maps.

The map is the entire background with the widgets on the top left corner (that sits on top of the map).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage (
 ## some layout here
       ##plotOutput('out_map')
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$out_map <- shiny::renderPlot(some_dataset)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add some CSS to your map so it takes the whole page. Here is an example using leaflet. Then you can add some `absolutePanel()` if you want to display some elements on top of the map.

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)

ui <- fluidPage (
  # set the height of a #map object with CSS
  tags$style(type = "text/css", "#map {height: calc(100vh - 10px) !important;}"),
  leafletOutput("map"),

  #add some panels above the map
  absolutePanel(id = "elements", class = "panel panel-default", top = 0, left = 0, width = 300, height = 300,
                tags$p("some other elements"))
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # generate the map with leaflet
  output$map <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet() %>% addTiles()
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```